# Getting NULL value back in UITableView from SQLite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

Program is running without issue
I can see the database being opened
When I add an item to the app, it shows up as **NULL** in the **UITableView**

I have unit tests that test each action: create, update, delete, and count.
These all pass

Here are my unit tests:

```
- (void)testToDoItemSQLite {
    NSLog(@" ");
    NSLog(@"*** Starting testToDoItemSQLite ***");

    ToDoItemSvcSQLite *todoitemSvc = [[ToDoItemSvcSQLite alloc] init];
    ToDoItem *todoitem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    todoitem.itemname = @"This was created by a unit test";
    [todoitemSvc createToDoItem:todoitem];

    NSMutableArray *todoitems = [todoitemSvc retrieveAllToDoItems];
    NSLog(@"*** number of todoitems: %lu", (unsigned long)todoitems.count);

    todoitem.itemname = @"This was created by a unit test";
    [todoitemSvc updateToDoItem:todoitem];

    [todoitemSvc deleteToDoItem:todoitem];

    NSLog(@"*** Ending testToDoItemSQLite ***");
    NSLog(@" ");
}
```

This is my **create**, **retrieve**, **update**, and **delete** code

```
#import "ToDoItemSvcSQLite.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"

@implementation ToDoItemSvcSQLite

NSString *databasePath = nil;
sqlite3 *database = nil;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"todoitem.sqlite3"];

        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"database is open");
            NSLog(@"database file path: %@", databasePath);

            NSString *createSql = @"Create table if not exists todoitem (id integer primary key autoincrement, itemname varchar(200))";

            char *errMsg;
            if (sqlite3_exec(database, [createSql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errMsg) !=SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table %s", errMsg);
            }

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"*** Failed to open database!");
            NSLog(@"*** SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (ToDoItem *) createToDoItem:(ToDoItem *)todoitem {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO todoitem (itemname) VALUES (\"%@\")", todoitem.itemname];
    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            todoitem.itemID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
            NSLog(@"ToDoItem added");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"*** ToDoItem NOT added");
            NSLog(@"*** SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}

    return todoitem;
}

- (NSMutableArray *) retrieveAllToDoItems {
    NSMutableArray *todoitems = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM todoitem ORDER BY itemname"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [selectSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"*** ToDoItems retrieved");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char *itemnameChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            ToDoItem *todoitem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
            todoitem.itemID = id;
            todoitem.itemname = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:itemnameChars];
            [todoitems addObject:todoitem];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"*** ToDoItems NOT retrieved");
        NSLog(@"*** SQL error %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }
    return todoitems;
}

- (ToDoItem *) updateToDoItem:(ToDoItem *)todoitem {
    NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE todoitem SET itemname=\"%@\" WHERE id = %li ", todoitem.itemname, (long)todoitem.itemID];
                           sqlite3_stmt *statement;
                           if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [updateSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                               if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)     {
                                   NSLog(@"*** ToDoItem updated");
                               }
                               else {
                                   NSLog(@"ToDoItem NOT updated");
                                   NSLog(@"*** SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                               }
                               sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                           }
    return todoitem;
}

- (ToDoItem *) deleteToDoItem:(ToDoItem *)todoitem {
    NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM todoitem WHERE id = %i",(int) todoitem.itemID];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [deleteSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"*** ToDoItem deleted");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"*** ToDoItem NOT deleted");
            NSLog(@"*** SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    return todoitem;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

@end
```

Here is the code that is executing all the actions

**Adds item**

```
- (IBAction)addToDoItem:(id)sender {

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    NSLog(@"saveToDoItem: Adding ToDoItem");
    ToDoItem *todoitem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    todoitem.todoitem = _toDoItem.text;
    [ToDoItemSvc createToDoItem:todoitem];

    //clears text field on save
    _toDoItem.text = @"";

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"saveToDoItem: todoitem saved");

}
```

**Deletes item**

```
- (IBAction)deleteToDoItem:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Deleting ToDoItem");

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

**Updates item**

```
- (IBAction)updateToDoItem:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"updatingToDoItem: Updating ToDoItem");
    toDoItemObject.todoitem = toDoItem.text;
}
```

**Populates UITableView**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"toDoItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [[ToDoItemSvc retrieveAllToDoItems]
                    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [toDoItem description];
    return cell;
}
```

I'm trying to to figure out why I am getting `NULL` back for my values.
When I look at the database, I don't actually see any entities in the table

Does this mean its not actually updating? I'm a little confused on this.

***EDIT***

I manually updated the database. I noticed that its not being read. I even replaced the database that xcode shows it is reading. Still nothing.

When this was running using archiving it worked great. Obviously different way of persisting data.

**EDIT**

It appears that persisting the data is in fact working but for some reason `NULL` is being inserted in the database. I tried editing the database to see if the table would reload and pick up the edited value. It didnt seem to work

[image: this is the app when it first runs]
[image: this is the tableview after entering an item]
[image: this is the value when you tape on it]
[image: what is being seen in the database]

**App loaded**
**After saving a new item**
**When viewing an item**

Comment: Show the code that calls these methods and reloads the table view.

Comment: Added the code you asked to see. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the difference of `todoitem.todoitem` and `todoitem.itemname`? You may be using `todoitem.itemname` instead of using `todoitem.todoitem`:

```
- (IBAction)addToDoItem:(id)sender {
    …
    todoitem.itemname = _toDoItem.text;
    [ToDoItemSvc createToDoItem:todoitem];
    ...
}

- (IBAction)updateToDoItem:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"updatingToDoItem: Updating ToDoItem");
    toDoItemObject.itemname = toDoItem.text;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [[ToDoItemSvc retrieveAllToDoItems]
                    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemname;
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this will help you!

---

**EDIT:**

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)addToDoItem:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    NSLog(@"saveToDoItem: Adding ToDoItem");
    ToDoItem *todoitem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    todoitem.itemname = _toDoItem.text;  // I edited
    [ToDoItemSvc createToDoItem:todoitem];

    //clears text field on save
    _toDoItem.text = @"";

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"saveToDoItem: todoitem saved");
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"toDoItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [[ToDoItemSvc retrieveAllToDoItems]
                        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [toDoItem itemname]; // I edited
    return cell;
}
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    toDoItem.text = toDoItemObject.itemname; // I edited
}
```

**ToDoItemSvcSQLite.m**

```
- (ToDoItem *) updateToDoItem:(ToDoItem *)todoitem {
    NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE todoitem SET itemname=\"%@\" WHERE id = %i ", todoitem.itemname, todoitem.id]; // I edited
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [updateSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"*** ToDoItem updated");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ToDoItem NOT updated");
            NSLog(@"*** SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    return todoitem;
}
```

Finally, instead of using `init` inside `ToDoItemSvcSQLite`, you should use `initialize`:

```
// ToDoItemSvcSQLite.m
static sqlite3 *database = nil;

+ (void)initialize {
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"todoitem"];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"database is open");
        NSLog(@"database file path: %@", databasePath);

        NSString *createSql = @"Create table if not exists todoitem (id integer primary key autoincrement, itemname varchar(200))";

        char *errMsg;
        if (sqlite3_exec(database, [createSql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errMsg) !=SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table %s", errMsg);
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"*** Failed to open database!");
        NSLog(@"*** SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
```

and comments this line inside `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
//    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

---

**EDIT AGAIN:**

It seems you changed the `identifier`:
[image]
[image]

You should use `viewToDoItem`:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"viewToDoItem"]) {
```

then:

```
// SecondViewController.m
#import "ToDoItemSvcSQLite.h"

- (IBAction)updateToDoItem:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"updatingToDoItem: Updating ToDoItem");
    toDoItemObject.itemname = toDoItem.text;
    [[ToDoItemSvcSQLite new] updateToDoItem:toDoItemObject];
}
```

Comment: It looks like its now not entering a `NULL` value. Its not updating still and my textfield isnt showing the object nor is it updating.

Comment: Can you post your project on GitHub?

Comment: Sure  Its already up. https://github.com/martylavender/LittleToDoApp/tree/addingsqlite   On a side note, I need to update my viewcontroller to be embedded in a navigation controller and get rid of the navigation bar. I had that done, but i ended up losing the last batch of changes. :)   Just an FYI that I realize how I have it running right now is not best practice.

Comment: I have tried your project, the problem will be resolved if you updated your code using my suggestion. I will edit my answer that causes it clearly.

Comment: Did I miss something on the edits? I'm going to feel stupid if I did.

Comment: I went through and double checked every change you suggested. It still does not show the item when i tap on it. There are no errors at all when running the code.

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking at this more.

Comment: It's my fault, I forget that update the `updateToDoItem` method in the `SecondViewController`

Comment: Youre an amazing person Bannings!!  Thank you so much for all of your help! It works the way it should now. I learned a lot from this. Are there situations where SQLite would be better than say, Core Data? Is using SQLite or Core Data a preference?

Comment: I'm glad that helped you:)  I prefer to use SQLite over CoreData. Actually CoreData uses SQLite as backend storage and able to use a model designer for your entities. http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/ios-data-storage-core-data-vs-sqlite/240168843

Comment: I was actually going to see if I could move this over to core data for the sake of learning. Do you have Skype?  The link you posted today, I was actually reading earlier today.

Comment: Sorry, my oral English is very bad :(

Comment: Do you have skype just to type?